# What are the differences between these two Apple TV models?

Tags: appletv

I have some Visa points which I am considering spending on an Apple TV.

According to my bank's website, Apple TV model they offer is `MD199C/A`. This seems to correspond to what Apple calls the *Order Number* (which is not the same as what Apple calls the *Model Number*).

Using [Mactracker](http://www.mactracker.ca/), I found that the latest 3rd Generation Apple TV's *Order Number* is `MD199LL/A`, which is a bit different from what the bank's website is saying, although quite similar.

Does anyone know if the Apple TV with the *Order Number* `MD199C/A` is the latest, 3rd generation model? What is the difference between `MD199C/A` and `MD199LL/A`, if any?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you in Canada by any chance? The MD199*C/A* code seems to be for the 3rd generation Apple TV in Canada, whereas the -*LL/A* code is the part number in the US. I'm not aware of any differences between the two (other than the limitations on Canadian iTunes, such as more limited iCloud TV/Movie accessibility).

You can verify these numbers by adding the Apple TV to your cart in the US or Canadian online Apple Stores.

Comment: Aha! So *that's* what it means! I am indeed in Canada. Thanks! :)